# Transformer Just Only Learning to Predict Dots and Padding Tokens in Translation Task

Tags: huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

I'm new to Natural Language Processing and Transformers. I started to learn about Transformers by implementing one from scratch using PyTorch. This is a translation-level encoder-decoder transformer that translates from English to Malayalam (A South Indian Language).

During the training of the network, even after a prolonged period, it only predicts padding tokens and sometimes the start tokens. To address this issue, I tried a technique where I accumulated text by appending the next sentences to the current ones in both the source and target languages until a maximum length was reached.

Eg:

"This is some text"

"This is some larger text which has more sequence length"

Accumulating,

"This is some text. This is some larger text which has more sequence length .... -> (max-seq-len)"

Then lined up both the source and translation to ensure that each sentence had a comparable length and was aligned with the translation.

Then after training it again, new problems came in, and now the network is only predicting dots "." since padding tokens are reduced, I am unsure of the reason If there is any problem with the decoder or encoder, or if is this the normal behavior of transformer models as it has not produced any translations even after 5 or 6 epochs. Well, considering the number of epochs is smaller, there might be some kind of progress in each training phase, at least we could see some kind of words emerging, but it is not happening, even in some cases, the loss is not decreasing.

### Things Used

Here are the things I used,

Dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/sidharthangn/ml-dataset

SentencePiece self-trained Tokenizer: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15ju7heON3szJ2s3DDtNrkjGjXuOFaW-t?usp=sharing

### Transformer Code

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import math
from math import sqrt
import torch.nn.functional as F


def scaled_dot_product_attention(query, key, value, mask=None):
    dim_k = query.size(-1)
    scores = torch.bmm(query, key.transpose(1, 2)) / sqrt(dim_k) # 32 x 200 x 200
    if mask is not None:
        scores = scores.masked_fill(mask==1, -1e9) # Very small negative number for masking
    attn_weights = F.softmax(scores, dim=-1)
    return attn_weights.bmm(value)


class EncoderPositionalEncoding(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super(EncoderPositionalEncoding, self).__init__()
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.2)

        # Create the positional encoding matrix
        pe = torch.zeros(config['source_contextual_length'], config['embedding_dim'])
        position = torch.arange(0, config['source_contextual_length'], dtype=torch.float32).unsqueeze(1)
        div_term = torch.exp(torch.arange(0,
                                          config['embedding_dim'],
                                          2).float() * (-torch.log(torch.tensor(10000.0)) / config['embedding_dim']))
        pe[:, 0::2] = torch.sin(position * div_term)
        pe[:, 1::2] = torch.cos(position * div_term)
        pe = pe.unsqueeze(0)
        self.register_buffer('pe', pe)
        self.pe.requires_grad = False

    def forward(self, x):
        # Add positional encoding to the input
        x = x + self.pe[:, :x.size(1)]
        return self.dropout(x)


class DecoderPositionalEncoding(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super(DecoderPositionalEncoding, self).__init__()
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.2)

        # Create the positional encoding matrix
        pe = torch.zeros(config['target_contextual_length'], config['embedding_dim'])
        position = torch.arange(0, config['target_contextual_length'], dtype=torch.float32).unsqueeze(1)
        div_term = torch.exp(torch.arange(0,
                                          config['embedding_dim'],
                                          2).float() * (-torch.log(torch.tensor(10000.0)) / config['embedding_dim']))
        pe[:, 0::2] = torch.sin(position * div_term)
        pe[:, 1::2] = torch.cos(position * div_term)
        pe = pe.unsqueeze(0)
        self.register_buffer('pe', pe)
        self.pe.requires_grad = False

    def forward(self, x):
        # Add positional encoding to the input
        x = x + self.pe[:, :x.size(1)]
        return self.dropout(x)

class EncoderEmbeddings(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__()
        self.token_embeddings = nn.Embedding(config['en_vocab_size'], config['embedding_dim'])
        self.layer_norm = nn.LayerNorm(config['embedding_dim'], eps=1e-12)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout()

    def forward(self, input_ids):
        embeddings = self.token_embeddings(input_ids)
        embeddings = self.layer_norm(embeddings)
        embeddings = self.dropout(embeddings)
        return embeddings

class DecoderEmbeddings(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__()
        self.token_embeddings = nn.Embedding(config['ml_vocab_size'], config['embedding_dim'])
        self.layer_norm = nn.LayerNorm(config['embedding_dim'], eps=1e-12)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout()

    def forward(self, input_ids):
        embeddings = self.token_embeddings(input_ids)
        embeddings = self.layer_norm(embeddings)
        embeddings = self.dropout(embeddings)
        return embeddings

# Encoder Attention Head
class AttentionHead(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embed_dim, head_dim):
        super().__init__()
        self.q = nn.Linear(embed_dim, head_dim)
        self.k = nn.Linear(embed_dim, head_dim)
        self.v = nn.Linear(embed_dim, head_dim)

    def forward(self, hidden_state, src_mask):
        attn_outputs = scaled_dot_product_attention(
            self.q(hidden_state),
            self.k(hidden_state),
            self.v(hidden_state),
            mask=src_mask
        )
        return attn_outputs


# Encoder Multi-head attention
class MultiHeadAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__()
        embed_dim = config['embedding_dim']
        num_heads = config['encoder_attn_heads']
        head_dim = embed_dim // num_heads
        self.heads = nn.ModuleList([AttentionHead(embed_dim, head_dim) for _ in range(num_heads)])
        self.output_linear = nn.Linear(embed_dim, embed_dim)

    def forward(self, hidden_state, src_mask):
        x = torch.cat([h(hidden_state, src_mask) for h in self.heads], dim=-1)
        x = self.output_linear(x)
        return x

# Position-Wise Feed Forward Layer
class FeedForward(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear_1 = nn.Linear(config['embedding_dim'], config['encoder_ffm_dim'])
        self.linear_2 = nn.Linear(config['encoder_ffm_dim'], config['embedding_dim'])
        self.gelu = nn.GELU()
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(config['dropout'])

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.linear_1(x)
        x = self.gelu(x)
        x = self.linear_2(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        return x

class TransformerEncoderLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__()
        self.layer_norm_1 = nn.LayerNorm(config['embedding_dim'])
        self.layer_norm_2 = nn.LayerNorm(config['embedding_dim'])
        self.attention = MultiHeadAttention(config)
        self.feed_forward = FeedForward(config)


    def forward(self, x, src_mask):
        hidden_state = self.layer_norm_1(x)
        # Applying skip connections
        x = x + self.attention(hidden_state, src_mask)
        # Attention with skip connection is passed to feed forward layer
        x = x + self.feed_forward(self.layer_norm_2(x))
        return x

class TransformerEncoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__()
        self.encoding = EncoderPositionalEncoding(config)
        self.embeddings = EncoderEmbeddings(config)
        self.layers = nn.ModuleList([
            TransformerEncoderLayer(config) for _ in range(config['encoder_layers'])
        ])

    def forward(self, x, src_mask):
        x = self.embeddings(x)
        x = x + self.encoding(x)
        for layer in self.layers:
            x = layer(x, src_mask)
        return x # Hidden contextual information from Encoder

# Encoder-decoder attention head
class CrossAttentionHead(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embed_dim, head_dim):
        super().__init__()
        self.q = nn.Linear(embed_dim, head_dim)
        self.k = nn.Linear(embed_dim, head_dim)
        self.v = nn.Linear(embed_dim, head_dim)

    def forward(self, hidden_state, encoder_out=None):
        attn_outputs = None
            # Cross Attention Encoder-Decoder Attention
        if encoder_out is not None:
            attn_outputs = scaled_dot_product_attention(
                self.q(hidden_state),
                self.k(encoder_out),
                self.v(encoder_out),
            )
        else:
            attn_outputs = scaled_dot_product_attention(
                self.q(hidden_state),
                self.k(hidden_state),
                self.v(hidden_state),
            )
        return attn_outputs

# Encoder decoder multi-head attention
class CrossMultiHeadAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__()
        embed_dim = config['embedding_dim']
        num_heads = config['encoder_attn_heads']
        head_dim = embed_dim // num_heads

        self.heads = nn.ModuleList([CrossAttentionHead(embed_dim, head_dim) for _ in range(num_heads)])
        self.output_linear = nn.Linear(embed_dim, embed_dim)

    def forward(self, hidden_state, encoder_out):
        x = torch.cat([h(hidden_state, encoder_out) for h in self.heads], dim=-1)
        x = self.output_linear(x)
        return x


class MaskedAttentionHead(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embed_dim, head_dim):
        super().__init__()
        self.q = nn.Linear(embed_dim, head_dim)
        self.k = nn.Linear(embed_dim, head_dim)
        self.v = nn.Linear(embed_dim, head_dim)

    def forward(self, hidden_state, d_mask):
        attn_outputs = scaled_dot_product_attention(
            self.q(hidden_state),
            self.k(hidden_state),
            self.v(hidden_state),
            mask=d_mask
        )
        return attn_outputs

class MaskedMultiHeadAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__()
        embed_dim = config['embedding_dim']
        num_heads = config['decoder_attn_heads']
        head_dim = embed_dim // num_heads
        self.heads = nn.ModuleList([
            MaskedAttentionHead(embed_dim, head_dim) for _ in range(num_heads)
        ])

        self.output_linear = nn.Linear(embed_dim, embed_dim)

    def forward(self, hidden_state, d_mask):
        x = torch.cat([h(hidden_state, d_mask) for h in self.heads ], dim=-1)
        x = self.output_linear(x)
        return x


class TransformerDecoderLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__()
        self.layer_norm_1 = nn.LayerNorm(config['embedding_dim'])
        self.layer_norm_2 = nn.LayerNorm(config['embedding_dim'])
        self.layer_norm_3 = nn.LayerNorm(config['embedding_dim'])

        self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout(config['dropout'])
        self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(config['dropout'])
        self.dropout3 = nn.Dropout(config['dropout'])

        self.masked_attention = MaskedMultiHeadAttention(config)
        self.attention = CrossMultiHeadAttention(config)
        self.feed_forward = FeedForward(config)

    def forward(self, x, encoder_out, d_mask):
        hidden_state = self.layer_norm_1(x)
        x = x + self.masked_attention(hidden_state, d_mask) # For training, mask is applied
        x = self.dropout1(x)
        hidden_state2 = self.layer_norm_2(x)
        x = x + self.attention(hidden_state2, encoder_out)
        x = self.dropout2(x)
        x = x + self.feed_forward(self.layer_norm_3(x))
        x = self.dropout3(x)
        return x

class TransformerDecoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__()
        self.encoding = DecoderPositionalEncoding(config)
        self.embeddings = DecoderEmbeddings(config)

        self.layers = nn.ModuleList([
            TransformerDecoderLayer(config) for _ in range(config['decoder_layers'])
        ])

        self.linear_layer = nn.Linear(config['embedding_dim'], config['ml_vocab_size'])

    def forward(self, x, encoder_out, d_mask):
        x = self.embeddings(x)
        x = x + self.encoding(x)
        # Pass the encoder output to the last decoder layer only
        for i, layer in enumerate(self.layers):
            if i == len(self.layers) - 1:
                x = layer(x, encoder_out, d_mask) # IF the last layer, apply encoder output
            else:
                x = layer(x, None, d_mask)  # Pass None for encoder output for other layers
        x = self.linear_layer(x)
        x = F.softmax(x, dim=-1)
        return x # The probability distribution from Decoder


class Transformer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__()
        self.encoder = TransformerEncoder(config)
        self.decoder = TransformerDecoder(config)

    def forward(self, x, y, src_mask=None, d_mask=None):
        # src-mask: For encoder mask - Padding mask
        # d-mask: For decoder mask - Both padding and Look-Ahead mask

        # x: [32, 200]
        # y: [32, 200]
        x = self.encoder(x, src_mask)
        x = self.decoder(y, x, d_mask)
        return x
```

Here is the summary of the Transformer,

1. Encoder and decoder blocks
2. The tokenized batch of source language "x" is passed through an encoder with the src_mask (padding mask)
3. The encoder's self attention takes it, applies masks before calculating scores and returns it.
4. Then the output of attention is passed to feed forward layer
5. The tokenized batch of target language "y" is passed to the decoder along with the "x" which is the output from the encoder
6. The decoder's masked multihead attention with look ahead mask takes it and returns the scores, then it is passed to cross attention, and finally the feed forward layer and applies linear and softmax.
7. The output from the encoder is only applied to the last decoder depending on how many layers of encoder and decoder is created, It is done inside the "TransformerDecoder" Class

Here are the configurations used

```py
config = {
    "en_vocab_size": len(en_vocab_mapping), # The size of the english vocabulary
    "ml_vocab_size": len(ml_vocab_mapping), # size of malayalam vocabulary
    "embedding_dim": 512, # Each token is converted into an embdding vector of dimension 512
    "source_contextual_length": en_tokenized.size(1), # Max_length for source language sequence
    "target_contextual_length": ml_tokenized.size(1), # Max_length for target langauge sequence
    "encoder_attn_heads": 8, # Number of attention heads in the encoder
    "decoder_attn_heads": 8, # Number of attention heads in the decoder
    "encoder_layers": 4, # Encoder num layers - For more contextual information, you need more encoder layers
    "decoder_layers": 4, # Decoder num layers - For more contextual information for translation, you need more decoder layers
    "encoder_ffm_dim": 2048, # Hidden dimension of feed forward layer in encoder
    "decoder_ffm_dim": 2048, # Hidden dimension of feed forward layer in decoder
    "dropout": 0.2 # Common Dropout over the network.

}
```

### Helper Functions

Loading the dataset as a Python list containing sentences,

```py
# Load Dataset

import multiprocessing

def read_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        return file.readlines()

# Define the file paths
en_file_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/cu_transformer/Datasets/en_corpus_new.en"
ml_file_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/cu_transformer/Datasets/ml_corpus_new.ml"

# Create a multiprocessing pool
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)  # Adjust the number of processes as needed

# Use parallel processing to read both files
source_language_list, target_language_list = pool.map(read_file, [en_file_path, ml_file_path])

# Close the pool
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Accumulate sentences but adding next sentences in the list of sentences to current one until a max length is reached to avoid excessive number of padding tokens.

```py
import re

def accumulate_text(source_list, target_list, max_sequence_length):
    """ Accumulating text until a specific length is reached to reduce the number of padding tokens """
    new_source_list = []
    new_target_list = []
    current_source_sequence = []
    current_target_sequence = []
    for source_sentence, target_sentence in zip(source_list, target_list):
        if len(current_source_sequence) + len(source_sentence.split()) <= max_sequence_length:
            current_source_sequence.extend(source_sentence.split())
            current_target_sequence.extend(target_sentence.split())
        else:
            new_source_list.append(" ".join(current_source_sequence))
            new_target_list.append(" ".join(current_target_sequence))
            current_source_sequence = source_sentence.split()
            current_target_sequence = target_sentence.split()
    new_source_list.append(" ".join(current_source_sequence))
    new_target_list.append(" ".join(current_target_sequence))
    return new_source_list, new_target_list
```

Remove noise:

```py
def remove_noise(text_list, pattern):
    regex_pattern = re.compile(pattern)
    cleaned_text_list = []
    for text in text_list:
        # Use the regex pattern to replace the matched pattern with an empty string
        cleaned_text = re.sub(regex_pattern, '', text)
        cleaned_text_list.append(cleaned_text)
    return cleaned_text_list
```

Tokenization:

```py
import torch

def tokenize_and_encode(sentences, tokenizer, add_start_end_tokens=False, max_seq_length=None):
    encoded_sentences = []
    for sentence in sentences:
        encoded_sentence = tokenizer.EncodeAsIds(sentence)
        if add_start_end_tokens:
            encoded_sentence = [tokenizer.PieceToId("<s>")] + encoded_sentence + [tokenizer.PieceToId("</s>")]
        if max_seq_length is not None:
            if len(encoded_sentence) > max_seq_length:
                encoded_sentence = encoded_sentence[:max_seq_length]  # Truncate if too long
            else:
                encoded_sentence += [0] * (max_seq_length - len(encoded_sentence))  # Pad if too short
        encoded_sentences.append(encoded_sentence)
    max_length = max(len(sentence) for sentence in encoded_sentences)
    padded_sentences = [sentence + [0] * (max_length - len(sentence)) for sentence in encoded_sentences]
    tensor_sentences = torch.tensor(padded_sentences)
    return tensor_sentences
```

Decoding the tokens to see if things are correct,

```py
def decode_tokens(tokenized_tensor, tokenizer):
    decoded_sentences = []
    for tokenized_sentence in tokenized_tensor:
        token_ids = tokenized_sentence.tolist()
        decoded_text = tokenizer.DecodeIds(token_ids)
        decoded_sentences.append(decoded_text)
    return " ".join(decoded_sentences)
```

Creating a vocabulary dict,

```py
def create_vocab_mapping(tokenizer):
    vocab_mapping = {tokenizer.IdToPiece(id): id for id in range(tokenizer.GetPieceSize())}
    return vocab_mapping
```

### Data Preprocessing

Loading the trained SentencePeice model for tokenizing

```py
en_model_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/cu_transformer/en_bpe2.model.model"
ml_model_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/cu_transformer/ml_bpe2.model.model"


sp_en = spm.SentencePieceProcessor()
sp_en.Load(en_model_path)

sp_ml = spm.SentencePieceProcessor()
sp_ml.Load(ml_model_path)
```

Selecting a list of sentences ,

```py
sentences = 32000
en_sentences = [language.strip("\n") for language in source_language_list[:sentences]]
ml_sentences = [language.strip("\n") for language in target_language_list[:sentences]]
```

Text accumulation,

```py
en_accumulated, ml_accumulated = accumulate_text(en_sentences, ml_sentences, 50)
```

Creating vocabulary for both source and target language

```py
ml_vocab_mapping = create_vocab_mapping(sp_ml) # English vocabulary
en_vocab_mapping = create_vocab_mapping(sp_en) # Malayalam Vocabulary
```

Tokenizing,

```py
en_tokenized = tokenize_and_encode(en_accumulated, sp_en, max_seq_length=70)
ml_tokenized = tokenize_and_encode(ml_accumulated, sp_ml, add_start_end_tokens=True, max_seq_length=70)
```

After tokenizing, the tensor contains valid tokens rather than a large number of padding tokens,

### Creating Padding and Look-Ahead Masks

```py
def create_padding_mask(tokenized_tensor, padding_idx=0):
    # Unsqueezing to match the dimension, I'm not sure if it is correct
    padding_mask = (tokenized_tensor == padding_idx).unsqueeze(1).float() # Convert True False to float
    return padding_mask

def create_look_ahead_mask(batch_size, sequence_length):
    look_ahead_mask = torch.triu(torch.ones(sequence_length, sequence_length), diagonal=1)
    batched_look_ahead_mask = look_ahead_mask.unsqueeze(0).expand(batch_size, -1, -1)
    return batched_look_ahead_mask
```

Pytorch Dataset and Dataloader

```py
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader

class TranslationDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, en_tokenized, ml_tokenized):
        self.en_tokenized = en_tokenized
        self.ml_tokenized = ml_tokenized
        self.length = len(en_tokenized)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.length

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        en_input = torch.tensor(self.en_tokenized[idx]).clone().detach()
        ml_input = torch.tensor(self.ml_tokenized[idx]).clone().detach()

        return {
            "en_tokenized": en_input,
            "ml_tokenized": ml_input
        }

batch_size = 16

dataset = TranslationDataset(en_tokenized, ml_tokenized)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, drop_last=True)
```

### Transformer Training

```py
import torch.optim as optim

transformer = Transformer(config)
optimizer = optim.Adam(transformer.parameters(), lr=0.00002)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
num_epochs = 10
transformer.to(device)

look_ahead_mask = create_look_ahead_mask(batch_size, ml_tokenized.size(1))
reverse_vocab_mapping = {value : key for key, value in ml_vocab_mapping.items()} # reversing target vocabulary to get characters when using token ID's


# Training 

from tqdm import tqdm

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    total_loss = 0.0
    data_iterator = tqdm(dataloader, desc=f"Epoch {epoch + 1}/{num_epochs} (DA)")
    for batch in data_iterator:
        en_batch, ml_batch = (
            batch['en_tokenized'].to(device),
            batch['ml_tokenized'].to(device)
        )
        source_padding_mask = create_padding_mask(en_batch).to(device)
        target_padding_mask = create_padding_mask(ml_batch).to(device)
        look_ahead_mask = look_ahead_mask.to(device)
        decoder_mask = torch.logical_or(look_ahead_mask, target_padding_mask).float()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = transformer(
            en_batch,
            ml_batch,
            src_mask = source_padding_mask,
            d_mask = decoder_mask
        )
        ml_batch_flat = ml_batch.view(-1)
        output_flat = output.contiguous().view(-1, config['ml_vocab_size'])
        loss = criterion(output_flat, ml_batch_flat)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        total_loss += loss.item()

    avg_loss = total_loss / len(dataloader)
    print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}, Avg. Loss: {avg_loss:.4f}")

    # Inference 
    if (epoch + 1) % 1 == 0:
        transformer.eval()
        for i, eval_batch in enumerate(dataloader):
            if i == 1:
                break
            en_eval_batch, ml_eval_batch = (
                batch['en_tokenized'].to(device),
                batch['ml_tokenized'].to(device)
            )

            predicted_ids = torch.argmax(output, dim=-1)
            predicted_tokens = [reverse_vocab_mapping[id.item()] for id in predicted_ids[0][1:] if id.item() in reverse_vocab_mapping]
            predicted_sequence = "".join(predicted_tokens)

            target_ids = ml_eval_batch.view(-1)
            target_tokens = [reverse_vocab_mapping[id.item()] for id in target_ids if id.item() in reverse_vocab_mapping]
            target_sequence = "".join(target_tokens)

            print("Actual: ", target_sequence)
            print("Predicted: ", predicted_sequence + '\n')
```

I tried different techniques to preprocess efficiently to make the transformer learn something, just something even some characters or words related to the language which might not be the translation, but at least we can ensure that the model is attending to the language.

But it is not attending to the language, but the dots and padding tokens,

I'm not sure if there are any issues with the architecture or data pre-processing. It appears that something unusual is happening either in the theory or the code. If you could offer any assistance in resolving this matter, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You